# Calculation of seasonality indexes for complex seasonality

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I want to forecast retail items (by week) using exponential smoothing.   I'm stuck right now in how to calculate, store, and apply the sesonality indexes.

The problem is that all examples I've found deal with a sort of simple seasonality.   In my case I have the following problems:
1.  Seasons don't occur on the same week every year:  they are movable.   Mardi-gras, lent, easter, and a few others.
2.  There are seasons that change depending on the year.  For example, there is a national holiday season.   Depending on whether the holiday is close to the weekend, customers will or will not leave town.  So it's kind of like having two seasons:  one where customers leave town, and one where they don't leave town.
3.  Sometimes two (or 3) seasons occur at the same time.   For example, we had "Mardi-Gras" season occurring at the same time as Valentine's season.
4.  Sometimes seasons change in duration.   For example, "Halloween season" started earlier this year.   Christmas is also another example, where it seems like every year we start earlier to carry the products.

It seems to me that I need to find a way to set some sort of "seasonal profiles" which then, depending on the particular scenario are somehow added to obtain the correct seasonal index.  Does that make sense?

Does anybody know where I can find practical information on how to do this?

Thanks,
Edgard

Answer (score 7):

For the kinds of seasonality you describe, the dummy variable approach is probably best. However, this is easier to handle in an ARIMA framework than an exponential smoothing framework. 
\begin{aligned}
y_t &= a + b_1D_{t,1} + \cdots + b_mD_{t,m} + N_t\\
N_t &\sim \text{ARIMA}
\end{aligned}
where each $D_{t,k}$ variable corresponds to one of the holiday or festival events. This is how the `arima` function in R will fit regression variables (as a regression with ARIMA errors, not as an ARIMAX model).

If you really want to stick with the exponential smoothing framework, there is a discussion of how to include covariates in my [2008 book on exponential smoothing](http://www.exponentialsmoothing.net). You might also look at my recent paper on [exponential smoothing with complex seasonality](http://robjhyndman.com/working-papers/complex-seasonality/) although the types of seasonal complications we discuss there are more difficult than the moving festival kind that you describe.

Comment: Hi Kwak and Rob.  Thanks for looking at this.  I wanted to use exponential smoothing because this is what I'm more familiar with.
I'm thinking that I need to learn on how to use the ARIMA framework.  Could you recommend a good book that would help me to learn enough about the ARIMA framework to apply such a dummy variable approach?

I have Bowerman's "Forecasting, Time Series, and Regression" and Levenbach "Forecasting: Practice and Process for Demand Management", which I used to learn about exponential smoothing.   I don't know if these go in sufficient detail for what I'd need.
Thanks!

Comment: Bowerman O'Connell and Koehler is quite good for introducing ARIMA models but I don't think it includes ARIMA with covariates. You could try my 1998 textbook which covers ARIMA modelling and regression with ARIMA errors at an introductory level. See http://robjhyndman.com/forecasting/ for details.

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix would be to include events dummies in your specification:

$(1) \hat{y_t}=\lambda_1 y_{t-1}+...+\lambda_k y_{t-k}+\phi_1 D_{t,1}+\phi_m D_{t,m}$

where $D_{t,m}$ is an indicator taking value $1$ if week $t$ has event $m$ (say Mardi gras) and 0 otherwise, for all $m$ events you deem important.

The first part of the specification $\lambda_1 y_{t-1}+...+\lambda_k y_{t-k}$ is essentially a exponential smoothers but with weight varying as a function of lags (and estimated by OLS).

This pre-supposes that you have at least 20 observations for each event (i.e. 20 'mardi gras'). If this is not the case, you can try to bundle some events together (say mardi gras and labour day).

The R to fit (1) is rather straighforward, assuming dlsales is stationnary and D is your matrix of dummy variables :

```
fit<-arima(dlsales,order=c(4,0,0),seasonal = list(order = c(1, 0, 0),period=52),xreg = D)
```

Starting from here, you can ask more specific questions about the part of my answer that are not familiar to you (i don't know what your level is in statistics).

Comment: Actually, the arima function in R will not fit your model (1). arima() does regression with ARIMA errors and your equation (1) is an ARMAX model.

Comment: Rob:> i've edited equation one. Can you point to a source where the difference(s) between armax and regression with arima errors are explain (or alternatively provide an intuitive explanation). Also, would you know of a R package that implements ARMAX models ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A first order ARMAX model with one covariate is
y_t = a + bx_t + cy_{t-1} + e_t
where e_t is iid zero mean.
The corresponding regression with ARIMA error is
y_t = a + bx_t + n_t where n_t = phi*n_{t-1}+z_t
and z_t is iid zero mean.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but i'm still a bit confused with the n_t in 'y_t = a + bx_t + n_t where n_t = phi*n_{t-1}+z_t and z_t is iid zero mean'. It seems that 'n_t' follows a moving average process (i.e. not autoregressive). Can you confirm that a regression with ARMA errors is actually a 'MAX' model (moving average + eXogeneous) ? Also, does it mean that regressions with ARIMA errors cannot be fitted by OLS ?

Comment: Also, I get exactly the same estimates when fitting 'arima(y,order= c(1, 0, 0),xreg=x)' from package stats and 'arimax(y,order= c(1, 0, 0),xreg=x)' (using the arimax function in package TSA). Does that mean that arimax() does not fit ARIMAX models ?

Comment: @kwak. First, n_t = phi*n_{t-1} + z_t is AR(1). A moving average process of order 1 would be n_t = theta*z_{t-1} + z_t. Second, an regression with MA errors is equivalent to a MAX model. But once you add AR terms in the error process, there is no equivalence between the two classes. Third, the arimax() function in TSA fits transfer function models, a special case of which is a regression with ARIMA errors. It does not fit ARIMAX models. I might write a blog post about this as it is hard to find the various model classes compared and discussed anywhere.

Comment: I've tried to summarise the various models at http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/arimax/